# Is msinfo32 able to read .nfo files containing indentation?

Tags: xml, windows, msinfo32

By default, `.xml` files labelled as `.nfo` which are created by `msinfo32` on Windows do not contain indentation. Is msinfo32 able to read an `.nfo` file manually indented using spaces and/or tabs?